# FB_Graph auth.from_cookie(cookies) works on IE , Opera only on localhost:3000 . works just fine on Chrome , Safari and Firefox

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

Here's a weird one: I use FB_graph to pick up the auth user from the cookie:. Intiate FB normally:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      :  <%=@appid%>, // App ID

  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Then I pick up the users on the controllers of each page:

```
config = YAML.load_file("./config/facebook.yml")[Rails.env]
   appid = config['client_id']
   secret = config['client_secret']
   auth =FbGraph::Auth.new(appid, secret)
   auth.from_cookie(cookies)
```

- all browsers works great on localhost:3000, I get my user no problem
- only chrom, safari and firefox works when actually hitting Facebook.com;
  **IE8 and Opera fails.**

I suspect some cookies restriction from IE and Opera. Any ideas?

---